# QtWebSockets not available on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, qml, websocket

I'm developing an Ubuntu Touch application which communicates with a server using WebSockets. Qt offers its own API since version 5.3, which can be used from a QML file by adding `import QtWebSockets 1.0`. However, despite having Qt 5.4 and the `libqt5websockets5` package installed on a 15.04 emulator image, I get the following error:

```
/path/to/Main.qml:2 module "QtWebSockets" is not installed
```

Is it possible to use WebSockets somehow with Ubuntu Touch's Qt?

Comment: FTR, the QML bindings to Qt's websockets are provided by `qml-module-qt-websockets`.  But that seems to be installed by default (at least on my device), so this is probably not your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `import Qt.WebSockets 1.0`.  This is the module name given in the qmldir file.

The [QML Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-qmlmodule.html) says that the `QtWebSockets` name was introduced in Qt 5.5; prior to that, the namespace was `Qt.WebSockets`.  Apparently, the old namespace is still active in 5.5, so I'd use it for the time being.

Comment: Are you kidding me.

Comment: @Pilot6 It does, indeed, give an answer. According to Qt's official documentation, it is supposed to be `QtWebSockets 1.0`, without the dot. So it was not an errata.